# ASP.NET MVC4 custom routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am planning to write custom ASP.NET MVC4 routing for the problem described below.

By default **[http://localhost:1603]** URL should show login page after user logged in then URL should contain username name in the URL like **[http://localhost:1603/username]** and other action methods should access like **[http://localhost:1603/username/profile]**.

Please guide me how to proceed with this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By default [http://localhost:1603] URL should show login page

To do this you can change `Default` Url Route's default values.Like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

You should change default `Controller` and Default `Action` name.For example I change them like: `Account` and `Login`.

> URL should contain username name in the URL like [http://localhost:1603/username]

Now you need a custom route,maybe something like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Custom",
            url: "{username}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "UserController", action = "Index" }
        );
```

With this route (I assume you have (`UserController` and an `Index` action in it):

```
http://localhost:1603/username
```

Will go to the Index action of UserController.

```
http://localhost:1603/username/profile
```

Will look for a `Profile` Action inside of `UserController`.Ofcourse you should get username from `RouteData` dictionary inside of your Action.Otherwise that seems pointless.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of MvcCodeRouting (there's a NuGet package for it). Take a look at the doco for base routes. It will do what you're trying to achieve.